# no matching function for call to message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime

Tags: ros, c++, message-filters, timesynchronizer, approximatetime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All
I am using ROS to subscribe some camera topics in two different ways.
Fist subscribe Topic from published messages and second subscribe them directly from bag file without playing bag the file , just read it directly.

in this program i have two different constructor one for published message and the other for reading file in each of the there are functions which do these tasks.

I have this error :

```
**/opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:152: error: no matching function for call to 'message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >::ApproximateTime()'**
```

these are my constructors :

```
//for reading bag file 

FOVISODOMETRY::FOVISODOMETRY(vector<string> cameraTopices,
        const string bagFileName, const char* visual_odom_frame_name)
{
/// some implementations 
}

////for subscribing from published massages 

FOVISODOMETRY::FOVISODOMETRY(const char* image_topic,
        const char* depth_image_topic, const char* camera_info_topic,
        const char* visual_odom_frame_name) :
        initialized_(false), fovis_initialized_(false), depth_image_(NULL),       depth_data_(
                NULL), grayscale_data_(NULL), rect_(NULL), odom_(NULL), node_(
                ""), private_node_("~"), camera_info_sub_(node_,
                camera_info_topic, 100), rgb_image_sub_(node_, image_topic,
                100), depth_image_sub_(node_, depth_image_topic, 100),image_sync_(
                ApproximateTimeCustomPolicy(10), camera_info_sub_,
                rgb_image_sub_, depth_image_sub_), odom_broadcaster_()

{
/// some implementations 
}
```

and these are the massage filter Synchronizer :

```
typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<
            sensor_msgs::CameraInfo, sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image> ApproximateTimeCustomPolicy;

message_filters::Synchronizer<ApproximateTimeCustomPolicy> image_sync_;
```

there is one point : when I omit the file reading constructor its has no error
but as soon as I add the second constructor the error appears .

please let me how can I have both of my constructors and also no error

thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49851/no-matching-function-for-call-to-message_filters::sync_policies::approximatetime/) by [raminzohouri](https://answers.ros.org/users/3438/raminzohouri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Christian

Thank you for you answer. It was a good hint , but in order to get ride of that error I have to do initialize the second constructor like this :

***FOVISODOMETRY::FOVISODOMETRY(vector cameraTopices,
const string bagFileName, const char* visual_odom_frame_name):image_sync_(
ApproximateTimeCustomPolicy(10), camera_info_sub_,
rgb_image_sub_, depth_image_sub_)***

but I still have one question : Although I don't use it in second constructor ,why  should I initialize this message_filter::synchronizer  ?
would you please help me on this !

thanks  in advance .
Ramin

***typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<
sensor_msgs::CameraInfo, sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image> ApproximateTimeCustomPolicy;
message_filters::Synchronizer image_sync_;***

---

Originally posted by [raminzohouri](https://answers.ros.org/users/3438/raminzohouri/) with karma: 26 on 2012-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-07**:
Please read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) before posting. Do not create answers for comments, updates and additional information. Instead, edit your original post or use the comment functionality. If you have additional questions, open a new question. This is not a forum.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-07**:
There is not default constructor, so you need to provide the parameters to the constructor by hand, otherwise the object cannot be created.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Initialize the approx time policy:

```
FOVISODOMETRY::FOVISODOMETRY(vector<string> cameraTopices,
        const string bagFileName, const char* visual_odom_frame_name) :  ApproximateTimeCustomPolicy(10)
{
/// some implementations 
}
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2